# render html in state string

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I use setState to update part of the html but I found the new update html is not rendered. Here is the code, [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y8r4/10/):

html:

```
<div>hello<br />world<br /></div>
<div id='content'></div>
```

js:

```
var Main = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {output: 'hello<br />world<br />'};
      },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>           
                {this.state.output}
            </div>
        );
        }
});

React.renderComponent(<Main/>, document.getElementById('content'));
```

I omit the part that update html from the server but the result is the same. How to let the string in state be rendered?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) to inject HTML as a string in React (but note that React won’t be able to use this markup in its virtual DOM):

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.output}} />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Y8r4/11/

The API for doing this is deliberately complex because this isn't safe to do routinely. React has protections against XSS, using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` circumvents those and opens you up to risk if you aren't sanitizing that data.

Comment: That works. Thanks. one more question, is this a common practice or also the best practice?

Comment: Storing HTML is not common but sometimes it is necessary (eg, you generate safe HTML on the server from user data, like a comment on stack overflow, and need to render it).

Comment: What would be the best way to sanitize this html?