# Binding methods in react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming

I'm getting an error when I try to bind values to the component function handleInput:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

However, when I insert the input element into the return statement at the bottom of the render method, it doesn't produce any errors. I'm guessing that this has something to do with the lifecycle of the render method, but I'm not sure.

Any insight is appreciated.

As for what the code does, it retrieves a string from this.props.info.text and replaces all instances of <= var[0-9] => with an html input box, then appends to a div. On user input, the values are propagated to a parent component.

```
export default class Line extends React.Component {

 constructor() {
   super();
 }

 handleInput(id, e) {
   console.log(id);
   this.props.handleCode(e.target.value);
 }

 shouldComponentUpdate(){
   if (document.getElementById('otherClass').innerHTML.length == 0){
     return true;
   }
   return false;
 }

 render() {
   var id = this.props.id;
   let codeVal = "";
   let codeDiv = document.createElement('div');
   if (typeof(this.props.info) !== 'undefined') {
     //breaks here
     codeVal = this.props.info.text.replace(/<= var[0-9] =>/, '<input type="text" onInput=this.handleInput.bind(this,id)></input>');
     let index = codeVal.indexOf('<');
     let splits = [codeVal.slice(0, index), codeVal.slice(index)];
     codeDiv.innerHTML = "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-6'>"+splits[0]+"</div><div class='col-md-6'>"+splits[1]+ "</div></div>";
     document.getElementById('otherClass').appendChild(codeDiv);
   }

   return(
     <div id='otherClass'></div>
   );

 }
}
```

Parent code:

```
export default class StateVal extends React.Component {
  handleCode(id, e){
    console.log("value propagated on user input");
    alert(e);
  }
  render() {
    return (
     <div className="col-md-6">
       <div className="card-block">
        < Line info={this.props.data.codeBody[0]} handleCode={this.handleCode} id={1} />
     </div>
   </div>
  );
}
}
```

Edit: the idea is that if I retrieve a text value through props like "int value = <=var0=>" how can I convert it to a responsive html input tag like

```
 int value = <input type='text' onInput=this.handleInput.bind(this, id)/>
```

and then render it in html

Comment: This is.... kinda crazy. Why are you creating elements using the dom api and appending them to your rendered component? Why not just make react components like `<div />` etc?

Comment: The html is supposed to be dynamic. That's why I used regex and can't just return a normal div.

Here's an example prop text value: int value = <= var0 =>
I'm supposed to convert it to int value = <input type="text" ..../>

Comment: Are you able to post the parent code? This is an ugly hack and I don't think this approach is going to work, if you could provide more information about the requirements you might get a better answer.

Comment: I agree with the other two. I'm not sure the dynamic you're trying to accomplish, but I'm sure it's something easily do-able with React. Also, you should use JSX to inject a function within React component.

Comment: @user2998285 everything in React is just JavaScript! And JavaScript is about as dynamic as it gets. Just render components based on state and props. Don't bother touching the DOM api whatsoever.

Comment: You cannot create DOM elements from within the `render` function. That’s just not how it works. If you need to manipulate the DOM manually, use the component lifecycle events.

Comment: https://medium.com/@john1jan/react-binding-revealed-aa458df8c136#.fd5z0vmjl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only write valid HTML when generating Html from a string with react.

`<input type='text' onInput=this.handleInput.bind(this, id)/>` is not valid: `onInput` is not a [HTML valid props](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

[Generating a jsx string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262702/how-to-render-a-string-with-jsx-in-react) to HTML with react is a special case requiring [babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262702/how-to-render-a-string-with-jsx-in-react).

I don't think you'll be able to insert jsx string in a component on the fly using a string but there is may be another solution. Split your string into an array and replace matching string by not a string code `"<../>"` but by a jsx element `<...>`. This jsx element will have the function binding as wanted to your component. I found a similar solution here: [Replace part of string with tag in JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474506/replace-part-of-string-with-tag-in-jsx)

Comment: Ok makes sense that you can't generate jsx strings. But onInput is a valid html event attribute. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Comment: Yes it is but in a javascript `<script>` tag. Not when redering html (with or without jsx). I just update the solution. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, that last part helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a proper way to render a string with react:

Use dangerouslySetInnerHTML to inject HTML as a string in React. Subject is treated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189559/render-html-in-state-string)

Regards

Comment: Thanks, I guess I wasn't really clear on my question, but the issue isn't simply just rendering the html, but also to ensure that handleInput is bound to 'this' and 'id.' That's where I'm having trouble. I keep getting errors saying that handleInput is not defined, or cannot read property 'bind' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the bind key word at the end like below instead of the example you have given.

```
onInput=this.handleInput(id).bind(this)
```

or just call this method here and bind it at the constructor level.

```
onInput=this.handleInput(id)

constructor() {
   super();
   this.handleInput=this.handleInput.bind(this);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately I still get errors. this.handleInput is not a function.

Comment: Also try with only one argument for testing purpose

Comment: Yes, the issue I believe is that onInput must be rendered in the return statement - hence this.handleInput is not a function. But I have modify the value of the props prior to returning,

Comment: So issue still exists ?

Comment: Can you please explain to hat you are trying to achieve ? You should not do string replacements to manipulate elements because there are more than one angle brackets

Comment: So you're saying that we shouldn't try to manipulate props within the component?

Comment: No, I mean you should not use string replacements to manipulate instead you can use logic inside components based on variables to render component code