# reactjs: wrapping existing html into a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Given existing html.

```
<component text="one"><h1>First Component</h1></component>
<component text="two"><h1>Second Component</h1></component>
<component text="three"><h2>Third Component</h2></component>
```

I wish to wrap these components in a react class, that obtains the `text` property from the existing DOM. In addition, the existing markup should be rendered inside the component.

I have a partially working solution:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as DOM from "react-dom";
import $ from "jquery";

export interface IWellProps {
    text: string
}

export class Well extends React.Component<IWellProps, {}> {
    render() {
        return <div>
            <span>{this.props.text}</span>
            <div>{this.props.children}</div>
        </div>;
    }
}

$("component")
    .each((i, e) => {
        DOM.render(<Well text={$(e).attr("text")}>{$(e).html()}</Well>, e);
        // version below renders html... the above does not.
        // is there not an api to convert text into `react.createElement` calls
        // DOM.render(<Well text={$(e).attr("text")}><h1>test</h1></Well>, e);
    });
```

My current implementation **partially works**, but **uses a jquery hack?** to create the components. I have a hunch that there will be some blowback when the components start using events and other react complexities.

- The text property is rendered from the original html as expected.
- The **inner html** is rendered as **text not html**.

[image]

Comment: Duplicated?http://stackoverflow.com/a/29189660/1181036

Comment: I don't think so, no. I am using `this.props.children` **not** `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, besides that, why should it make a difference, the html I am attempting to insert is inside the JSX (it is not text), if I added the markup manually, instead of using `{$(e).html()}` would it not render as `HTML`?

Comment: I am also asking if there is a better pattern for rendering the components besides using jquery?

Comment: `DOM.render(<Well text={$(e).attr("text")}><h1>TEST</h1></Well>, e);` renders as HTML, so how do I replace `<h1>TEST</h1>` with the original nodes as I am attempting to do?