# extract plain text from wikipedia API to my website as a paragraph

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, react-hooks, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to get the plain text from article about Berlin from wikipedia API and implement it as a paragraph to my website - all in ReactJs environment

I have this url: 
[Link to wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&titles=Berlin)

which works fine in browser, then try to fetch data like under below sanbox:
[Link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/gallant-margulis-xr0go?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

which usually works with most of APIs 
but here I have no idea what to do - in state I got object where I can't actually reach the article text. I can for example reach the URL adress, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please put the code etc. in the question instead of linking to a sandbox

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working solution.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-nightingale-rwv2u

Here are a couple of points for you to consider:

- Your query URL had a ' at the end which made it return no results
- You need to extract the content of the results to show them in your HTML, that's what the getFirstPageExtract function does
- Rendering HTML from state has its downsides, please read [render html in state string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189559/render-html-in-state-string)

Comment: Thanks ! You're my God :):) ...now just need to read it like 100 times to understand what's happening here and we're good :) thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Remove the typo in your url `'`

I've added `loading` and `error` state as well because I think that it is a very common practice to handle `loading` and `error` state. I've also make your contents into an array and render your array using `map`

Note that I've used [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) props and it is known to be very dangerous and risky to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [contents, setContents] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  const url =
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&titles=Berlin";

  const extractAPIContents = (json) => {
    const { pages } = json.query;
    return Object.keys(pages).map(id => pages[id].extract);
  }

  const getContents = async () => {
    let resp;
    let contents = [];
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      resp = await fetch(url);
      const json = await resp.json();
      contents = extractAPIContents(json);
    } catch(err) {
      setError(err);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
    setContents(contents);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getContents();
  }, []);

  if (loading) return 'Loading ...';
  if (error) return 'An error occurred';
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Article</h1>
      {contents.map(content => <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} />)}
    </div>
  )
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here is a working demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-davinci-m5j9i?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thanks ! this one is great solution too, ...God.... i feel like i'm so weak now in React :( , really appreciate the attention !

Comment: Feel free to ask me anything if you don't understand anything in the codes. :)
This is just an example, of course in `Production` you will really think twice before using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and accessing object property.